# How can I range the variable in sigma(sum) in CPLEX

Tags: sum, cplex

I'm quite new to this platform and I need your help. This photo is what I want to express into CPLEX.
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeRWj.png)

But the thing is I don't know how to range the variables in sigma. Please look at the sigma and you can find the ranges j=o~7 and j=8~15. I declared just like this.[declare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23J7R.png) and wrote my "subject to" part. [subject to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXdh1.png)

I got errors and I don't know how to fix it correctly.

Comment: Hi, why don t you post .mod and .dat so that other users could help you ?

Comment: I resolved this problem thank you.